# why genID() method in In-memory-web-api does not generate an ID?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I used angular-in-memory-web-api to simulate a data server. when I post a new model to add to database, I get an error because of property id, I think that the genId() method in the service does not works. my model is:

```js
export class WorkHouse implements WorkHouseInterface{
  id: number = 0;
  title: string = '';
  code: string = '';
  manager: string = '';
  startDate: Date = new Date();
  endDate: Date = new Date();
  evalUnit: string = '';
}
```

and, InMemoryDataService is:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService{
  createDb() {
    const workHouses = [{id:1, title: 'work1', code: '523', manager: 'xyz', startDate: new Date(), endDate:new Date(), evalUnit: '1'},
                        {id:2, title: 'work2', code: '345', manager: 'abc', startDate: new Date(), endDate:new Date(), evalUnit: '2'}];
    return {workHouses};
  }

  genId(workHouses: WorkHouse[]): number {
    return workHouses.length > 0 ? Math.max(...workHouses.map(workHouse => workHouse.id)) + 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

so, when I fill the properties of below new model via a form except property id:

```
    this.newWorkHouse = {id:0, title:'',code:'',manager:'',startDate:new Date(''),endDate:new Date(''), evalUnit:''};
```

and post it via calling addWorkHouse method in WorkHouse.service:

```js
  /** POST: add a new workHouse to the server */
  addWorkHouse(workHouse: WorkHouse): Observable<WorkHouse> {
    return this.http.post<WorkHouse>(this.workHouseUrl, workHouse, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newWorkHouse: WorkHouse) => this.log(`added workHouse w/ id=${newWorkHouse.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<WorkHouse>('addWorkHouse'))
    );
  }
```

by below code:

```js
this.workHouseService.addWorkHouse(this.newWorkHouse).subscribe(workHouse => {
          this.workHouses.push(workHouse)});
```

but I get an error, and the model is not saved. I think the genId() method does not generate an unique Id for that model. how can I handle this error?

Comment: the missing closing curly bracket in your last code-snippet is a copy-paste-error?

Comment: I have not any syntax error. Every thing goes correct, even I get the model array from database by calling getWorkHouses() method in the service. I get error when adding new model. even the first new model (note that its Id =0) is saved! Because its id (0) is still unique in the database, but for the second new model, an error is rised and because two IDs with same values (0) must be saved in the database, its means that genId() does not works to generate Id for each new model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define property id as any to accept null or undefined initial value:

```js
export class WorkHouse implements WorkHouseInterface{
  id: any = null;
  title: string = '';
  code: string = '';
  manager: string = '';
  startDate: Date = new Date();
  endDate: Date = new Date();
  evalUnit: string = '';
}
```

and in the form, initial the newWorkHouse:

```js
    this.newWorkHouse = {id:null, title:'',code:'',manager:'',startDate:new Date(''),endDate:new Date(''), evalUnit:''};
```

or before post the newWorkHose to the server, assign the null or undefined to to its id property:

```
this.newWorkHouse.id = null;
```

consider the `if (item.id == undefined)` statement in post method in the back-end server of in-memory-web-api to call `genId(...)` method to generate id:

```js
// Create entity
  // Can update an existing entity too if post409 is false.
  protected post({ collection, collectionName, headers, id, req, resourceUrl, url }: RequestInfo): ResponseOptions {
    const item = this.clone(this.getJsonBody(req));

    // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
    if (item.id == undefined) {
      try {
        item.id = id || this.genId(collection, collectionName);
      } catch (err) {
        const emsg: string = err.message || '';
        if (/id type is non-numeric/.test(emsg)) {
          return this.createErrorResponseOptions(url, STATUS.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTRY, emsg);
        } else {
          console.error(err);
          return this.createErrorResponseOptions(url, STATUS.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            `Failed to generate new id for '${collectionName}'`);
        }
      }
    }
    
    //......
```